# Listview set color for single item By position When the dialog box opens

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I tried to set checked when I open the dialog box by the following code:

```
 private void openDilog() {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), R.style.NewDialog);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    mListView =dialog.findViewById(R.id.mylist);
    listItem = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myarray);
    aAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1, listItem);
    mListView.setAdapter(aAdapter);
    dialog.show();
    mListView.setItemChecked(1,true);
  }
```

my xml layout `mylayout`:

```
   <LinearLayout
      ......>
        <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mylist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:listSelector="#ffffff"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried to put the check at position 1 but it didn't

I want to change the background color or force the selection item

Note that this dialog box is inside the framement

Comment: no android developer here :(

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is to create an AlertDialog and use the setSingleChoiceItems method on that dialog:

```
private void openDialog() {
    Context context = getActivity();
    if (context == null) return;
    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    adb.setSingleChoiceItems(R.array.myarray, 1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });
    adb.show();
}
```

Note: this will automatically select the item at position 1 (2nd item in the list based on starting at index 0)

Comment: Thanks for the answer .. Now there is no "listview" Well you changed the design style by switching from "listview" to "radioButton", I have no problem but how do I put this inside the design of the dialog box .. i hope to see my dialog code how i put my code insaid special style

Comment: If you need something more custom than the standard AlertDialog, you can use `adb.setView(someView)`.  It will be up to you to set your own adapter with onClickListener in it

Comment: i have error with this line 
` final AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(context,R.style.NewDialog);
        adb.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        adb.setContentView(R.layout.s_name);`

Comment: and setView not working with api 15 only 21 and above